# characteristic of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I got 4 short question about characteristic.

1)  What is characteristic of integral domain D which suffices $20 \cdot 1_D=0_D=12 \cdot 1_D$

2) Let $A=\{0,1,a\}$ be a integral domain what is car($A$)?

3) R is a ring, $0_R\neq1_R$ and $a^6= a $ for every $a\in R$. What is the car($A$)?

In first question. car(D) should divide gcd(20,12)=4. But how do we decide it is 1,2 or 4?

Comment: The questions look familiar. Have you searched the site?

Comment: yes. couldnt find any duplicate. can you atleast give a hint

Comment: Hints: What do you know about the characteristic of an integral domain? Have you heard of Lagrange's theorem? Have you checked how the land lies with $a=1+1, a=1+1+1$ et cetera? $F$ is not a subgroup but if you drop one element you do get a ring - not a subring, mind you, but a ring anyway.

Comment: yes. $\bar 1$ shouldnt be inside.

Comment: The characteristic in (1) could be any of $1$, $2$ or $4$, there is no information that narrows it down any further.

Comment: @whaca No that is false. The ring must be an integral domain and as such cannot have characteristic $4$, and characteristic $1$ doesn't really make any sense if our rings are unital.

Comment: Ah, yes, forgot about being a domain. Any questions about (2) or (3) OP?

Comment: it cant be 4 because prime but why cant 1? is it because $1_R \neq 0_R$?

Comment: Yes that is what it means to be unital. In general the only ring that we would say has "characteristic 1" is the $0$ ring, which is an integral domain but not a ring with a distinct unity and so is sometimes not considered a ring. But really this is just silly definition balancing and I think the category of rings with unity behaves better if we do not demand $1 \neq 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the unique ring of characteristic 1 is the ring where $0_R=1_R$.

1) You should know that any integral domain has prime characteristic. Hence the unique possibility is that $car(D)=2$.

2) $(A,+)$ is a group with 3 elements. This means that the additive order of $1$ is 3.

3) From $$(1_R+1_R)^6=1_R+1_R$$ you get $$62 \cdot 1_R = 0_R$$
so $car(A)$ divides $62$. Do the same with $(1_R + 1_R +1_R )$ and get
$$726 \cdot 1_R = 0_R $$
so $car(A)$ divides $726$. Since $\gcd(62, 726)=2$, the characteristic is $2$.

Comment: do we always say for finite integral domain sets' characteristic are their orders?

Comment: @St3114 The characteristic of a unital ring is the additive order of the identity (equivalently, the exponent of the underlying additive group, or the nonnegative generator of the principal ideal kernel of the unique unital ring homomorphism $\Bbb Z\to R$). One can talk about rings having characteristics regardless of whether or not they are a domain, they can have characteristic even if they are non-unital (see my first parenthetical definition). No, the characteristic of a ring is not the cardinality of its underlying set.

Comment: @whacka I see. Is there any easier way to do 3rd question?

Comment: @St3114 I don't see any hard way to do the 3rd question. You could consider $1+a$ and prove it's $0$ to determine $a$ is $-1$ and hence $A\cong\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ if you want, but it's really no simpler than saying $1$ has nontrivial additive order dividing $3$ hence equal to $3$. If you think these are difficult proofs for question (3) then you should try to absorb them better.

Answer (score 1):

I assume 'integral domain' to mean 'associative commutative ring with identity element and exactly one zero divisor'. Henceforth,  denotes identity element of integral domain Я.
(Note that a zero ring, strictly speaking, has *no* zero divisor.)

Question 2:
If a∊{, } then char(Я)=2, otherwise char(Я)=3. (In the latter case there's exactly *one* such integral domain Я, up to isomorphy. No choice regarding ring operations: a+a=, +=a, -a=, a²=.)

Question 3:
If a⁶=a for all a∊Я, then -=(-)⁶=. Since ≠, we have ord()=2.

Nice excercise sheet from algebra course.